# need help figuting out what i did wrong

Tags: python

i started with a simple def for x+y=result then changed everything to make a definition for adding colors and getting a result. I added if, elif conditions.  all my answers are printing purple and i cant fig out what i did wrong.

```
def Add_colors(color1, color2):
    result=(color1, color2)
    if('blue', 'red') or ('red', 'blue'):
       result="purple"
    elif("red", "yellow") or ("yellow", "red"):
        result="orange"
    elif("yellow", "blue") or ("blue", "yellow"):
        result="green"
    return result

print(Add_colors("red", "blue"))
print(Add_colors("yellow", "blue"))
print(Add_colors("red", "yellow"))
```

Comment: The first if statement does an implicit boolean evaluation of the two tuples, which evaluates to True since non-empty collections are 'truthy'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-empty tuples always evaluate to True, and when you don't compare then these are itself interpreted as conditions ( :-O ) You are not comparing with the value of the argument, you need to try like this:

```
def Add_colors(color1, color2):
    result=(color1, color2)
    if result in [('blue', 'red'), ('red', 'blue')]:
       result="purple"
    elif result in [("red", "yellow"),("yellow", "red")]:
        result="orange"
    elif result in [("yellow", "blue"),("blue", "yellow")]:
        result="green"
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

A tuple is not a condition, a non-empty tuple always evaluate to be `True`, try running `bool(('blue', 'red') or ('red', 'blue'))`, `bool((1,2,3))` and `bool(())` to test it yourself,

to fix your code,

```
def Add_colors(color1, color2):
    result = set((color1, color2))
    if result == set(('red', 'blue')):
       result="purple"
    elif result == set(("red", "yellow")):
        result="orange"
    elif result == set(("yellow", "blue")):
        result="green"
    return result

print(Add_colors("red", "blue"))
print(Add_colors("yellow", "blue"))
print(Add_colors("red", "yellow"))
```

Comment: with this method, you only use: if result == set(('red', 'blue')):  do you have to use or after that and type the colors in the oposite like (red, blue) or (blue, red), or when you use set does it not matter the order of the colors at all and it will run regardles?

Comment: If you use `set`, the ordering of the element inside the `set` does not matter in comparison, if you have more than 2 elements, using `set` is actually better as it makes the code cleaner and *faster* processing time.

Answer (score 0):

By because your logic was stop at here

```
if('blue', 'red') or ('red', 'blue'):
```

It always true. So result is "purple"
You can fix like @Burning Alcohol posted above.